# Custom error with grape when using http_basic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication, ruby-grape, grape-api

Im using http_basic method in Grape in my rails app, I have got it working but would like to provide a custom error if the authentication details are incorrect.

```
http_basic do |username, password|
  @project = Project.where(api_key: username).first
end
```

This works but I cant seem to be able to throw a custom error if the project cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

```
http_basic do |username, password|
  @project = Project.where(api_key: username).first
  @project ? true : error!('Unauthorized. Invalid or expired token.', 401) 
end
```

Don't forget to check that password is also valid
:-)